# How to restrict users to enter only numbers from 1 to 12 in asp.net with c# using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a textbox in asp.net web form. I want to force users to enter only numbers from 1 to 12.  How can I do this using java script?

I have searched a lot and have read different validation functions, but I could not find something similar to this.

Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new *input type=number* in HTML5. This won't require any javascript, but may not work on older browsers.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="12">
```

More here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a nice way. But I want to use this in my function in my aspx page, for example, "default.aspx.cs". Although this input`s name and id, is "quantity", I see the error: "The name 'quantity' does not exist in the current context" in "default.aspx.cs". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you can use HTML5 then it is extremely easy.

```
<input type="number"  min="1" max="12">
```

You can refer to example here [HTML5 number](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number)

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I said in comment for kmandov, I have a problem. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtboxID.ClientID%>").change()(function(){
    var value=$("#<%=txtboxID.ClientID%>").val();

    if(value<13&&value>0)
    {
      //your action 
    }
    else
    {
      alert("use only numbers between 1 to 12");
    }
});
    });
<script>
```

Comment: Your answer and another answer from Fubo are right. That is why I just mention in comments which they are right. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression if you want to go with JavaScript way.

If you only want to allow digits and commas, `^[-,0-9]+$` is your regex. If you also want to allow spaces, use `^[-,0-9 ]+$`.

However, if you want to allow proper numbers, better go with something like this:

`^([-+] ?)?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$`.

In my opinion the best way is to go with HTML 5 *input tupe= number* as mentioned above by other contributes. Don't make easy things complex

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I said in comment for kmandov, I have a problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: if you want to check with c# code  use this method return "str.All(char.IsDigit);" where str is the .Text of the textbox

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get what you mean.Would you mind explain more please?  I don't want to check with c# code. I should use this input in my c# code, but It can't recognize my input. This is my problem.